# VB .NET FTP Write a file line by line

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, ftp

In VB.NET is it possible to write a file line by line directly to FTP?

In the application I can write files using this:

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("FILE.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("line1")
file.WriteLine("line2")
file.Close()
```

Do you know a short example how I can write a file directly to FTP or if is possible this?

Comment: `FtpWebRequest` supports the `FTP` `APPE` (Append) command. It has to be supported on the other side, too. I posted a complete example here: [Direct Uploading New Ftp listbox Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570566/direct-uploading-new-ftp-listbox-lines?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `StreamWriter` to `FtpWebRequest` request stream:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.txt")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream(),
      writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(stream)
    writer.WriteLine("line1")
    writer.WriteLine("line2")
End Using
```