# How would you edit a .txt file, over FTP, using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am an amateur programmer using VB.Net. One of the programs I am currently trying to make is a chat program. To help you understand how my program works I think it is nescessary to introduce the key ways it works.

*Instead of PCs communicating to eachother, each PC appends their message to a text file through FTP
*PCs will read the text file located on the Internet and put that on the main history textbox.
*The old version of this program was designed to be used on a school network. On my school network, each user could access a shared hard drive on the network, and the old version would write to a text file on the shared hard drive, and then display said text when a timer instructed PC to do so.

The new problem is the fact that I am not sure how would I go about using FTP, editing a file on there without having to save the file to the PC, and then uploading it baack.

*This chat program will be scarcely used- the program wouldn't be used enough that saving a file and re-uploading it would be slow and cause info loss - not enough usage.

Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: The [List of FTP commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands) includes APPE for append. You just need to search (Google etc.) for a way to use FTP in VB.NET.

Comment: The `APPE` command in a FtpWebRequest is activated setting [WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp) as the [FtpWebRequest.Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.method) property. Here's a sample usage in VB.Net: [Direct Uploading New Ftp listbox Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51578812/7444103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet to help you get started. It appends a String to a file on the server. If the file does not exist it is created.

```
Dim text As String = "Hello World!"
Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)

Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://<url>/test1.txt")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile
request.ContentLength = data.Length

Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
```